# SQL query that gets parents that don't have a certain value in child table 1 and child table 2

Tags: postgresql

I have a parent table that has a few child tables. the parent child relations are one 2 many. I have to get parents where their children don't have certain values. The values in child tables are different so if one table has the value it doesn't mean that it's in the other tables.

I've tried just normal INNER JOIN and WHERE NOT IN (codes), but it got all records.
The code below doesn't work because of the UNION. With the UNION parents that don't have the codes in child table 2 and the ones that don't have the codes in child table 2.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PAYSLIP.id, PAYSLIP.year, PAYSLIP.month 
FROM (
    SELECT p.id, p.year, p.month
    FROM history_payslip_data p 
    INNER JOIN history_payslip_data_hours pu ON p.id = pu.payslip_id 
    INNER JOIN history_payslip zg ON p.payslip_id = zg.id 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 
         FROM history_payslip_data_hours pu2
         WHERE p.id = pu2.payslip_id
         AND pu2.code IN ('code1', 'code2', 'code3')
    )
    AND (p.employee_id IN (2) AND p.payslip_type = 'PL' AND zg.locked = TRUE)   
    UNION 
    SELECT p.id, p.year, p.month
    FROM history_payslip_data p 
    INNER JOIN history_payslip_data_other pd ON p.id = pd.payslip_id 
    INNER JOIN history_payslip zg ON p.payslip_id = zg.id 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 
         FROM history_payslip_data_other pd2
         WHERE p.id = pd2.payslip_id
         AND pd2.code IN ('code1', 'code2', 'code3')
    )
    AND (p.employee_id IN (2) AND p.payslip_type = 'PL' AND zg.locked = TRUE)

) AS PAYSLIP
ORDER BY PAYSLIP.year DESC, PAYSLIP.month DESC;
```

I want to get parents that don't have the codes in any child table.

Comment: in simple words you want to get parent with having column(e.g age) set to NULL. right?

Comment: @G.B  Nope... not NULL, but the parents where in the child tables column, does not have a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `LEFT JOIN`ing against a CTE for each type of child table you'd like to suppress parent results for (I changed `history_payslip.id` to `payslip_id` to make the joins simpler):

```
WITH hours AS (
SELECT hpd.payslip_id, hpd.employee_id, hpd.year, hpd.month
  FROM history_payslip_data hpd
  --JOIN history_payslip hp USING (payslip_id)
  JOIN history_payslip_data_hours h USING (payslip_id)
 WHERE h.code in ('code1', 'code2', 'code3')
), other AS (
SELECT hpd.payslip_id, hpd.employee_id, hpd.year, hpd.month
  FROM history_payslip_data hpd
  --JOIN history_payslip hp USING (payslip_id)
  JOIN history_payslip_data_other o USING (payslip_id)
 WHERE o.code in ('code1', 'code2', 'code3')
)

SELECT hp.payslip_id as pid, hpd.employee_id as eid, hpd.year, hpd.month
  FROM history_payslip_data hpd
  JOIN history_payslip hp USING (payslip_id)
  LEFT JOIN hours h USING (payslip_id, employee_id)
  LEFT JOIN other o USING (payslip_id, employee_id)
 WHERE hpd.payslip_type = 'PL'
   AND hp.locked IS true
   AND h.payslip_id IS NULL
   AND o.payslip_id IS NULL
```

Here's how I'm testing this, with the query above saved as `new-query.sql`:

main.sql:

```
CREATE SCHEMA so54111738;
SET search_path=so54111738;

\i ./tables.ddl
\i ./setup.sql
--\i ./query.sql
\i ./new-query.sql

DROP SCHEMA so54111738 CASCADE;
```

tables.ddl:

```
CREATE TABLE history_payslip (
  payslip_id int,
  locked boolean
);

CREATE TABLE history_payslip_data (
  id serial,
  employee_id int,
  payslip_id int,
  payslip_type text,
  year int,
  month int
);

CREATE TABLE history_payslip_data_hours (
  payslip_id int,
  code text
);

CREATE TABLE history_payslip_data_other (
  payslip_id int,
  code text
);
```

setup.sql:

```
/* these two groups of inserts represent a payslip plus an hours row that means it should be excluded */
/* payslip 1 for employee 2; hours entry with code 4 */
INSERT INTO history_payslip (payslip_id, locked) VALUES (1, true);
INSERT INTO history_payslip_data (payslip_id, payslip_type, employee_id, year, month) VALUES (1, 'PL', 2, 2018, 12);
INSERT INTO history_payslip_data_hours (payslip_id, code) VALUES (1, 'code4');

/* payslip 1 for employee 2; hours entry with code 3 */
INSERT INTO history_payslip (payslip_id, locked) VALUES (1, true);
INSERT INTO history_payslip_data (payslip_id, payslip_type, employee_id, year, month) VALUES (1, '??', 2, 2018, 12);
INSERT INTO history_payslip_data_hours (payslip_id, code) VALUES (1, 'code3');


/* these two groups of inserts represent a payslip plus an other row that means it should be excluded */
/* payslip 2 for employee 3; other entry with code 4 */
INSERT INTO history_payslip (payslip_id, locked) VALUES (2, true);
INSERT INTO history_payslip_data (payslip_id, payslip_type, employee_id, year, month) VALUES (2, 'PL', 3, 2018, 11);
INSERT INTO history_payslip_data_other (payslip_id, code) VALUES (2, 'code4');

/* payslip 2 for employee 3; other entry with code 3 */
INSERT INTO history_payslip (payslip_id, locked) VALUES (2, true);
INSERT INTO history_payslip_data (payslip_id, payslip_type, employee_id, year, month) VALUES (2, '??', 3, 2018, 11);
INSERT INTO history_payslip_data_other (payslip_id, code) VALUES (2, 'code3');


/* this group of inserts represents a payslip that should be returned because it has no matching hours or other entries */
/* payslip 5 for employee 5; hours entry with code 4 */
INSERT INTO history_payslip (payslip_id, locked) VALUES (5, true);
INSERT INTO history_payslip_data (payslip_id, payslip_type, employee_id, year, month) VALUES (5, 'PL', 5, 2018, 10);
INSERT INTO history_payslip_data_hours (payslip_id, code) VALUES (5, 'code4');
```